# How to qualify methods as static in Scala?

Tags: scala, static, static-methods

I have a class

```
class MyClass {
  def apply(myRDD: RDD[String]) {
    val rdd2 = myRDD.map(myString => {
      // do String manipulation
    }
  }
}

object MyClass {

}
```

Since I have a block of code performing one task (the area that says `"do String manipulation"`), I thought I should break it out into its own method. Since the method is not changing the state of the class, I thought I should make it a `static` method.

How do I do that?

I thought that you can just pop a method inside the companion object and it would be available as a static class, like this:

```
object MyClass {
  def doStringManipulation(myString: String) = {
    // do String manipulation
  }
}
```

but when I try `val rdd2 = myRDD.map(myString => { doStringManipulation(myString)})`, scala doesn't recognize the method and it forces me to do `MyClass.doStringManipulation(myString)` in order to call it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing is "wrong". This is the correct way to access object's methods: `ObjectName.method`. Alternatively, you can import it into names space by putting this somewhere in scope (or at the top of the file): `import MyClass._`.

Comment: It's interesting that the import of MyClass._  is needed since MyClass is defined within the file.

Comment: `MyClass` is defined within the file, so you do not need to import it (if it was in a different package, you would also need `import that.package.MyClass`).  But `doStringManipulation` is defined inside `MyClass`, so you do need to import that. You could also just do `import MyClass.doStringManipulation`.  `_` is a wildcard, that just imports everything.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In Scala there are no *static* methods: all methods are defined over an object, be it an instance of a class or a singleton, as the one you defined in your question.

As you correctly pointed out, by having a `class` and an `object` named in the same way in the same compilation unit you make the object a *companion* of the class, which means that the two have access to each others' `private` fields and methods, but this does not mean they are available without specifying which object you are accessing.

What you want to do is either using the long form as mentioned (`MyClass.doStringManipulation(myString)`) or, if you think it makes sense, you can just import the method in the `class`' scope, as follows:

```
import MyClass.doStringManipulation

class MyClass {
  def apply(myRDD: RDD[String]): Unit = {
    val rdd2 = myRDD.map(doStringManipulation)
  }
}

object MyClass {
  private def doStringManipulation(myString: String): String = {
    ???
  }
}
```

As a side note, for the `MyClass.apply` method, you used the a notation which is going to disappear in the future:

```
// this is a shorthand for a method that returns `Unit` but is going to disappear
def method(parameter: Type) {
  // does things
}

// this means the same, but it's going to stay
// the `=` is enough, even without the explicit return type
// unless, that is, you want to force the method to discard the last value and return `Unit`
def method(parameter: Type): Unit = {
  // does things
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should follow scala's advice.

`val rdd2 = myRDD.map(MyClass.doStringManipulation)`

Answer (score 2):

Write this inside the class then it will work as expected.

`import MyClass._`