# How to use JUnit 5's @BeforeAll in Scala

Tags: scala, junit, tdd, junit5

[Junit5](https://junit.org/junit5/) has introduced [@BeforeAll](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/BeforeAll.html) to signal that the annotated method should be executed before all tests in the current test class. However it has requirement of method being [static](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/issues/122).

I have following structure in my Scala test suite:

```
class BaseTest extends MockitoSugar {

  @BeforeAll
  def codeNeedeForAllTests() = {   <== this does not work as as it is not static
    println("calling codeNeedeForAllTests")
    // other code
  }
}
```

and other test classes:

```
class IndexerTest extends BaseTest {
  @Test
  def add() = {
     //test code
  }
}
```

So I want that `codeNeedeForAllTests` get called before all tests, however the catch is `@BeforeAll`'s requirement of method being static, for which I need to make [codeNeedeForAllTests as object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48180356/1610034) to have static method in Scala.

Now in Scala, a class can not extend an object and and [object also can not extend object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7625040/1610034).

I also tried creating [companion object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3530727/1610034) of `BaseTest`, but that also did not work, any clean approach to do this?

Comment: strange when I created the companion object of `BaseTest` it worked

Answer (score 0):

`@BeforeAll` methods in JUnit Jupiter (a.k.a., JUnit 5) do **not** have to be `static`.

The link you provided is to JUnit 4.

[This link](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-annotations) is to JUnit Jupiter.

Excerpt:

> Denotes that the annotated method should be executed before all @Test, @RepeatedTest, @ParameterizedTest, and @TestFactory methods in the current class; analogous to JUnit 4’s @BeforeClass. Such methods are inherited (unless they are hidden or overridden) and must be static (unless the "per-class" test instance lifecycle is used).

And that links to the documentation on [Test Instance Lifecycle](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-instance-lifecycle).

Thus, you should be able to annotate your test class with `@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)` and declare your `@BeforeAll` method as non-static.

Comment: I am not able to get this done even after putting `@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)` at top of class. Not sure why not working.

Comment: Sounds odd. Perhaps you should post a simplified version of your project online and link to it for others to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `FunCpec`.

```
package net

import org.scalatest._

class Test extends FunSpec with BeforeAndAfterAll {

    override def beforeAll: Unit = {
        println("beforeAll")
    }

    describe("running a test") {
        println("in describe")

        it("should do something") {
            println("in my test")
            assert(true)
        }
    }
}
```

If u'll test it in REPL:

```
scala> test
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/kmmere/Workspace/Work/scalatest_before/target/scala-2.11/test-classes...
in describe
beforeAll
in my test
[info] Test:
[info] running a test
[info] - should do something
[info] Run completed in 99 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 1
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 1, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] All tests passed.
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Oct 19, 2015 4:32:56 PM
```

Don't forget to include dependency of `scalatest` in yor `build.sbt` file:

```
"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.0-SNAP10" % Test
```

**class FunSpec** - facilitates a “behavior-driven” style of development (BDD), in which tests are combined with text that specifies the behavior the tests verify.

***Recommended Usage***: For teams coming from Ruby's RSpec tool, FunSpec will feel familiar and comfortable; More generally, for any team that prefers **BDD**, FunSpec's nesting and gentle guide to structuring text (with describe and it) provide an excellent general-purpose choice for writing specification-style tests.