# Can singleton object extend a trait?

Tags: scala, singleton

I want to extend a trait from Scala object and override those methods which are in trait. So my doubt is those methods will become static to that Object
or instance methods, and is this good approach to extend from trait to Scala Object. Please help on this

```
trait A{
  def show:Unit
}

object B extends A{
  override def show(): Unit = { 
    println("inside Object")    
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[There are no static methods in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48180356/5205022). `object` can indeed extend a `trait`. Overriden methods, like `show`, do not become static methods, instead they belong to a **single instance** of `B.type`. This is the singleton pattern provided by Scala's `object` definition facility.

Try the following in Scala REPL:

```
object B
B
```

It should output something like

```
res0: B.type = B$@5688722f
```

Note how the **value** `B` has type `B.type`, so `B` is just a value/instance, nothing to do with statics.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I think a common example/usecase of what you've just described is extending the `App` trait and overriding the `main` definition.

```
object test extends App
{  
  override def main (args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello, let's get started")
  }
}
```

In general though, why don't you define the class itself to extend the trait?

If you are going to instantiate new instances of `B` using `B()` (instead of `new B()`) it makes sense to do this.

```
trait A{
  def show:Unit
}

object B { // companion aka singleton object
  def apply(){
    ...
  }
}

class B extends A{
  override def show(): Unit = { 
    println("inside Object")    
  }    
}
```