# Calling a static method on a variable rather than class

Tags: java, scala

So I am writing some Scala tests for some Java code (I am very new at both of them). What I am trying to do is instead of calling `.create` on the `Configuration` class, I want to call `create` on the `conf` mock object. How can I go about doing this?

When I try to call `.create` on a mock of the `Configuration` class, I get an error since (I think) `.create` is a `static` method from a custom `abstract` `Configuration` java class

Scala test code:

```
var conf: Configuration = mock[Configuration]

when(Configuration.create("var1","var2", "var3")).thenReturn(testConfiguration)
```

Thanks!

Comment: static methods are not ment to be called on an object in java, however you could create an non-initialzied variable and do: MyClass class; class.staticMethod(); or create a inner class that has a static method like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884004/is-calling-static-methods-via-an-object-bad-form-why
In Scala, there are no static methods, however you could create some "pseudo-static" with implementing a singleton

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make my scala method static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48178192/how-do-i-make-my-scala-method-static)

Comment: The posted snippet doesn't make a lot of sense. And having a static method that needs to be mocked seems very wrong. Add a [mcve] please.